# How could I define list variables in my ecore model?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

I have a class named `File` and another named `Folder` in GMF (Graphical Modeling Framework). In class definition, `Folder` has a method that returns `List<File>`, so how could I define in my ecore model?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a containment reference on Folder class. The reference will be 1-to-many and type of reference should be File

Suppose EClasses Folder and File are already created.
Right-click on Folder EClass "New Child" -> "EReference"
Select the EReference and open properties view for it
Now while in EReference is selected perform the following in the properties view:

1. Containment -> switch to true
2. EType -> select File
3. Name -> type "files"
4. Upper Bound -> type -1 (means infinity)

This is it. The generated Folder class would have getter and setter for files feature.

Comment: thanks, i have solved my problem. by the way, can you give me some advice or resources that help me study GMF?